# push element array laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

sory help me for add element to array

this code my controller

```
$datas = PengembalianAset::select('kd_brg', 'nm_brg', 'nm_lgkp_brg', 'keterangan', 'ruang_id', 'no_ikn')
        ->find($request->id)->toArray();

foreach ($datas as $safety) {
            $dataSet[] = [
                'new element' => 1,
                $safety,
            ];
        }
        print_r($dataSet); exit;
```

[array output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtJrv.png)

[image]

and I want to push 1 element to my data

[which I expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcFo4.png)

[image]

but the result is like this
[But the result is like this, not what I expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhdzX.png)

[image]

Comment: array unshift `new_element` inside `$safety` first,  then push it inside `$dataSet`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following :

```
$datas = PengembalianAset::select('kd_brg', 'nm_brg', 'nm_lgkp_brg', 'keterangan', 'ruang_id', 'no_ikn')->find($request->id)->toArray();

foreach ($datas as $safety) {
  $safety['new_element'] = 1;
  $dataSet[] =   $safety;
}
print_r($dataSet); exit;
```

or also you can add it to your exist array

```
$datas = PengembalianAset::select('kd_brg', 'nm_brg', 'nm_lgkp_brg', 'keterangan', 'ruang_id', 'no_ikn')->find($request->id)->toArray();

foreach ($datas as &$safety) { //Passing by Reference
  $safety['new element'] = 1
}
print_r($datas); exit;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this also -

```
$datas = PengembalianAset::select('kd_brg', 'nm_brg', 'nm_lgkp_brg', 
         'keterangan', 'ruang_id', 'no_ikn', '1 AS `new element`')
         ->find($request->id)->toArray();
```

Get `1` as `new element` from the query only. As it will have the same value. No need for the extra loop.

Comment: its no work for me but in laravel adding DB:raw if in laravel for adding query free @AlivetoDie. maybe if i'm not wrong :) @ Sougata Bose

Comment: This should work. If it is not working then you can use `DB::raw()`

Answer (score 0):

change your foreach from

```
foreach ($datas as $safety) {
            $dataSet[] = [
                'new element' => 1,
                $safety,
            ];
        }
```

to

```
foreach ($datas as $safety) {
            $safety['new element'] = 1;
            $dataSet[] = $safety;
        }
```

Comment: your solution is exact of mine :-D

Comment: thankyou for your answer but error 
( Illegal string offset 'new element' )

Comment: i'm just writing an answer and didn't see your answer. so sorry for that but it was originally mine.

Comment: "new element" is not an illegal offset.